# How can I launch the NSOpen dialog when my SwiftUI app starts on macOS?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I have a tiny one-view SwiftUI app on macOS that acts as a front-end for [hledger](https://hledger.org). I need it to prompt the user for a ledger file to use preferably with the minimum amount of extra code or user UI interactions (in that order of preference), and I would like for this to happen precisely once at launch ideally. My first idea was to do something like this:

```swift
func openHledgerFile() -> String {
    let panel = NSOpenPanel()
    panel.allowsMultipleSelection = false
    panel.canChooseDirectories = false
    if panel.runModal() == .OK {
        return panel.url?.path ?? ""
    }
    return ""
}


struct ExpenseControllerView: View {
    private var ledgerFileName: String {
       openHledgerFile() // Real code would make this condidional
    }

    var body: some View {
                Text("Opened file \(ledgerFileName)")
    }
}
```

however, that never shows the dialog at all.

Is there a way I can tell the declarative subsystem "if this value is not initialised then don't show the view, show the dialog"? I would like to avoid having an enitre view with just a "do thing" button.

Comment: *if this value is not initialised* raises the question: What does `initialised` mean precisely and how do you check it?

Comment: It means that the file picker has not executed yet and I’d like for it to not have to be checked by design by forcing the file picker to run first.